# using crt for encrypting files/texts

Tags: encryption, certificates, gnupg

I work with GPGTools under Mac where, after creating a public/private key pair for myself, I usually get .asc from other users, import it and then I'm good to go.
Now, I got an actual certificate from a user. I tried exporting the pubkey with

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in user.crt
```

but I'm then unable to import it in GPGTools and get the error `no valid OpenPGP data found`. From the certificate the properties of the pubkey are:

```
Algorithm: RSA Encryption / Key size: 1024 bits / Key usage: Encrypt, Verify, Wrap, Derive
```

Given the above I wonder if my approach is fundamentally wrong and I'm trying to pair apples with bananas. Could anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks a lot,
Joe

Comment: Looks like this answers my question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84904/how-do-i-convert-a-gpg-certificate-to-a-crt-certificate-that-can-be-imported-int

Comment: Yes, this is the point: while OpenPGP and OpenSSL mostly use the same algorithms, they're not compatible with each other.